# Value stored in session variable expires much earlier than the value mentioned in sessionState

Tags: c#, .net, session-variables

I tried setting the sessionState value to 10 days in web config file

```
<sessionState timeout="14400" />
```

But the value in the session expires in like 1-2 hours

The contents in the Bin folder did not change, no one accessed the farm when I checked this

```
    userDetail = SetRoles(somevalue);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetail"] = userDetail;
```

The value in this session expires in an hour. Is there any additional setting that I need to make?

Comment: If this is an InProc session (which is default), then you keep every session in memory for 10 days after the user last interacted with the system. Or until the app-pool recycles, maybe because of memory pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Modify session state in web.config as follows

```
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="14400" />
```